# How to organize projects and build directories in Meson (build system)

Tags: build, embedded, meson-build

Let's say you're in a team building the following:

- Several applications for embedded devices
- Sometimes, the same application is supposed to be implemented on multiple different devices.

  - In cases where the devices are similar enough, you build a HAL and keep multiple drivers etc. together with the business logic in the same binary.
  - In cases where the devices are too different (e.g. not enough memory for all the differing parts or too complicated to handle side-by-side) you build different binaries. The business logic can still be compiled from the same source code in this case.
- Components that may be reused for >1 embedded device. E.g. drivers for peripherals, defined by an interface and 1 or more implementations for different devices.
- Unit tests (for PC)
- HW tests (with PC <-> embedded communication)
- PC tools related to your work (e.g. programming devices, communicating with devices, ...)
- Scripts for release packaging
- ...

As far as I understand, Meson supports only 1 "host" when you cross-compile so there's a need to setup multiple build dirs. This is not an issue in itself.

How would you organize file structure (source and build files), repositories, meson build dirs etc?

...and anything I missed :)

Comment: You can check my [blog post](https://dev.to/elvisoric/project-structure-using-meson-build-and-c-19m1) as a starting point and to get an idea.